# In Laravel 5.3, how to get the Job ID after we dispatch a job to the job queue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-5.3

In Laravel 5.3, in the controller, we can dispatch a job to the job queue like this:

```
$job = (new JobClass())->onQueue('queuename');
dispatch($job);
```

In the Job class which is using `InteractsWithQueue` trait, in the `handle` function, we can get the Job ID like this:

```
$this->job->getJobId();
```

But, I would like to get the Job ID in my controller after I use the `dispatch($job)`.

How to get the Job ID in controller?

If there is no such function available, can we extend the `dispatch` helper function to add this function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `dispatch()` function will return the Job id:

```
$job = (new JobClass())->onQueue('queuename');
$jobId = dispatch($job);

dd($jobId);
```

Comment: may I know how you search for the API documentation for the `dispatch` function? I tried to search for it in `https://laravel.com/api/5.3/` but could not find it. What is the URL for this function?

Comment: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`

Comment: @Baik Ho in laravel 5.5 it is protected so can not get the job id is their a way we can get the job id in laravel controller. ?

Comment: @usama See my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329206/how-to-get-the-queued-job-from-job-id-in-laravel/47616524#47616524

Answer (score 0):

Its a quite old question. But maybe who came across this post by google.
Laravel is firing an event after a job is queued. `Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobQueued`

You can add a listener to this event and reach almost all infos incl. The DB id int your event listener.

In your EventServiceProvider attach your listener. In my app it is the `JobQueuedListener` file

```
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobQueued;

protected $listen = [
        JobQueued::class =>[
            JobQueuedListener::class
        ],
```

In the `JobQueuedListener` file you can now access the event var.

```
public function handle(JobQueued $event)
{
    $this->event  = $event;
    $mainListener = $event->job->class ?? '';
    if ($mainListener == 'App\Listeners\IpBlockedListener') {
        $this->addIdToIpBlockedModel();
    }

    }
```